# How do I mock the HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC using Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq, httpcontext

```
[TestMethod]
public void Home_Message_Display_Unknown_User_when_coockie_does_not_exist()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    context
        .Setup(c => c.Request)
        .Returns(request.Object);
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    controller.HttpContext = context; //Here I am getting an error (read only).
    ...
 }
```

my base controller has an overrride of the Initialize that get's this requestContext.  I am trying to pass this along but I am not doing something right.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Where can I get more information on mocking my RequestContext and HttpContext using Moq?  I am trying to mock cookies and the general context.

Answer (score 71):

HttpContext is read-only, but it is actually derived from the ControllerContext, which you can set.

```
 controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( context.Object, new RouteData(), controller );
```

Comment: This one worked for me by allowing me to set a mock HttpContext on the controller.

Answer (score 43):

Create a request, response and put them both to HttpContext:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://mySomething/", "");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
HttpContext httpContextMock = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
```

Comment: The question is about the *Base classes, ie HttpRequestBase, not HttpRequest - not sure why both are needed myself and even more annoying that they are "sealed".  No way to set LogonUserIdentity :(

Comment: If they're marshalled my reference, it's still possible via remoting, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ChrisKimpton: As a last resort, there's always _reflection_ ;-)

Comment: This works when attaching it to the controller, like this:
  controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(httpContextMock), 
    new RouteData(), 
    controller);

Comment: yes. you can indeed set .LogonUserIdentity  -- _request.Setup(n => n.LogonUserIdentity).Returns((WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent));

Comment: All these are abstract classes, you cannot instantiate them.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks user 0100110010101.

It worked for me and here i had an issue while writing the testcase for the below code :

```
 var currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

And here is the lines which solved the problem

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController();
//Mock Request.Url.AbsoluteUri 
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://mySomething", "");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
HttpContext httpContextMock = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContextMock), new RouteData(), controller);
```

Might be helpful for the others.

Comment: I can't seem to use the HttpRequest type - is that something else now?

Comment: This is not useful because all the fields in HttpRequest are immutable

Comment: I also had to use this to fix the RouteData  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57005125/1594274

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I used the ControllerContext to pass a fake Application path:

```
[TestClass]
public class ClassTest
{
    private Mock<ControllerContext> mockControllerContext;
    private HomeController sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        sut = new HomeController();
    }
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        sut.Dispose();
        mockControllerContext = null;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_Should_Return_Default_View()
    {

        // Expectations
        mockControllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath)
            .Returns("/foo.com");
        sut.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;

        // Act
        var failure = sut.Index();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(failure, typeof(ViewResult), "Index() did not return expected ViewResult.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why'd you need to pass a fake application path?

Comment: The MVC code will execute it and throw a null exception if it's not there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how you can set this up: [Mocking HttpContext HttpRequest and HttpResponse for UnitTests (using Moq)](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/mocking-httpcontext-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-unittests-using-moq/)

Note the extension methods which really help to simplify the usage of this mocking classes:

```
var mockHttpContext = new API_Moq_HttpContext();

var httpContext = mockHttpContext.httpContext();

httpContext.request_Write("<html><body>".line()); 
httpContext.request_Write("   this is a web page".line());  
httpContext.request_Write("</body></html>"); 

return httpContext.request_Read();
```

Here is an example of how to write a Unit Test using moq to check that an HttpModule is working as expected: [Unit Test for HttpModule using Moq to wrap HttpRequest](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/unit-test-for-httpmodule-using-moq-to-wrap-httprequest/)

Update: this API has been refactored to

- [HttpContextFactory.cs](https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp/blob/master/FluentSharp.Web_4_5/Classes/HttpContextFactory.cs)
- these multiple ***Http**** [Extension Methods](https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp/tree/master/FluentSharp.Web_4_5/ExtensionMethods) files

Comment: Links are broken - please include the code in your answer

Answer (score -1):

```
var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
httpResponse.Content = new StringContent("Your response text");
```