# Creating a mock URL referrer in ASP.Net MVC for Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm currently testing my application and am stuck on trying to figure out how to create a custom fake URL referrer.  I've tried to hard code it, but am getting an error that it is read-only.  Here is what I've tried so far:

```
fakeController.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

as well as,

```
fakeController.Request.UrlReferrer = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

I've searched the web for some ideas on how to create a fake/mock URL referrer for my fake controller, but have had no luck.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Note: I'm using Visual Studios built-in unit testing facilities.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your suggestions so far, I would be more than willing to use any other unit testing system outside of Visual Studio, unfortunately here at my work we are only allowed to use Visual Studio's built-in system, so I gotta work with what I've got.  Thank you though, it's good to know these options are out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Recommend changing to a Mock Framework such as NMock or Rhino Mock which allows you to create those, and returns an specific value for a given call such as the get method in that property.

Answer (score 8):

Create a mock request for the HttpContext, then set up an expectation on the Request that returns a Uri.  Example using RhinoMocks.

```
 var context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
 var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
 request.Expect( r => r.UrlReferrer ).Returns( new Uri( "http://www.yahoo.com" ) ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
 context.Expect( c => c.Request ).Returns( request ).Repeat.Any();

 fakeController.HttpContext = context;
```

Comment: +1 I started to type a similar answer using Moq but you beat me to it

Comment: hey tvanfosson, tried messing around with this code snippet, but I'm getting and error for context.Expect()

Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' to 'System.Web.HttpRequest'

Answer (score 5):

tvanfosson's Answer is in the right direction but is a little outdated. (Granted OP couldn't use MOQ, added for future reference)

```
    // Dependency Mocks initialization ....
    ....
    MyController controller = new MyController(mock.Object, ...dependencies...);

    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.Setup(r => r.UrlReferrer).Returns(new Uri("http://www.site.com"));
    context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    // Setting the HttpContext
    // HttpContext is read-only, but it is actually derived from the
    // ControllerContext, which you can set. 
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, 
        new RouteData(), controller);
    //target.HttpContext = context.Object; // outdated
```

[HttpContext from Controller context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to create an entire mock HttpContext in order to accomplish this unfortunately.  Rather than hardcoding this, I would highly suggest using mocks, as this will let you avoid setting up pieces of the object that you don't actually need.

I would suggest checking out [Scott Hanselmann's MvcMockHelpers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) post to get some idea of what is involved (it includes code for both Rhino and Moq).