# Unit test method with HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

```
    public SupportedBrowser GetBrowser()
    {
        string agent = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];

        if (agent.Contains("iPad"))
        {
            return new iPad();
        }
        else
            return new InternetExplorer7();
    }
```

I setup a unit test for the method above using Microsofts unit test tool (MS-Test?).  Because the unit test is not a web site, there is no HttpContext.  I can think of two solutions:

A.  Add an optional param: `GetBrowser(bool debug = false)`.  This allows current code to execute without refactor.  Then modify the method to create a mock context or hard coded user-agent when debug is true.

B.  Add Dependency injection.  Get the context from somewhere else.  Though, I think I'll need to drop in IoC via ninject to get this automated.  Thats a lot of work.

Can you think of something better or improve upon these ideas?

Note, this method is housed in a class library.  I want to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your agent string is a natural place for mocking. Instead of getting the agent string from the request context inside this method, pass it or inject to the method/class. That way you've got control over it during testing and runtime.

Comment: I like DI, but as I posted in my question I think this is going to be quite a bit of work.  Since the HttpContext.Request.UserAgent is readonly I cant set for testing.  I may need to go all out using something akin to mallows98's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq.  Trying to avoid that route.

Comment: Don't inject the context, inject the agent string. That will give you total control over it.

Comment: @Rick Liddle - +1 oh haha.  Simple, as most great ideas are.  Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes to see the solution is a different set of eyeballs. :-)