# How to fake HttpContext.Current for UTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to write some UT for my code

which uses HttpContext.Current

How can I fake this object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mock the HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC using Moq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the WatiN library and tools.  You can fake a IE thread.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Phil Haack HttpSimulator for that purpose :

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use a commercial tool like [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com) to fake the HttpContext directly, without wrapping it in your own code:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(()=> controller.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"])
    .WillReturn("YourID");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you own that code, don't use HttpContext directly. Use some interface that abstract HttpContext away.
Then replace the implementation of that interface in unit tests.