# Mocking Request.Browser.Type in Unit Tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mocking, httpcontext

I am trying to test an `ActionResult` that returns a partial view.  This action checks to see if the user is using IE7 or IE8 and will return a different partial if the user is using IE7 or 8.  This is because the java-script we are using doesn't quite work with 7 or 8 so we will treat it differently.

I have left out the model creation because I want to just focus on the `Request.Browser.Type`.

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string listing)
{
    if (model.Count > 1 && Request.Browser.Type != "IE8" && Request.Browser.Type != "IE7")
    {
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Features/Views/Video/MultiVideo.cshtml", model);
    }
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Features/Views/Video/SingleVideo.cshtml", model.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Ultimately I want to know two things

1. How can you Mock the `Request.Browser.Type` if at all?
2. Is this even good practice to do inside your controller?  If not what solutions would be better?

What I have tried:

`var browser = new Mock<HttpContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            browser.Setup(x => x.Request.Browser).Returns("IE9");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered my own question while writing the question (which I find often happens for me). However, I wasn't able to find much on this anywhere else so I figured I'd share my solution.

With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq) SO question I came up with this to be able to Mock browser types

```
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        // This line would do the job
        request.Setup(b => b.Browser.Type).Returns("IE9");

        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
                                            context.Object,
                                            new RouteData(),
                                            controller);
```

I still am uncertain if this is a good idea or not to do in your controller. Any thoughts would be appreciated.