# Dependency injection and HttpContext.Current? How to make this class testable?

Tags: c#, testing, tdd, ninject

I'm very new to testing and just starting out and want to know how could I make my `AuthorizationService` testable.

Reason is that I can't use Ninject to inject HttpContext.Current.Request into my `AuthorizationService(IHttpContext context)` since it has no interface.

How should I proceed?

#### Code

```
public class AuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService
{
    private readonly string _token;

    public AuthorizationService()
    {
        var headerValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("Token");
        var paramValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.GetValues("Token");
        var headerToken = string.Empty;
        var paramToken = string.Empty;

        // ... some logic ...

        this._token = headerToken;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just some random function that will return the token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetToken()
    {
        return this._token;
    }
}
```

Comment: that question has been asked a million times, just search for mocking httpcontext

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mock the HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC using Moq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you inject current context as contributor parameter.

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthorizationService>()
    .To<AuthorizationService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", x => HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `HttpContext` does not have an interfacce `IHttpContext`, it does have an abstract base class `HttpContextBase` which you can use for mocking.

[MSDN documentation for `HttpContextBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx).

Personally I prefer separately injecting `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` so there is less to mock (dependant on your method of course).