# How can I prepare an argument of type HttpContext for a method?

Tags: c#, http, web

I am trying unit-test a method. The method takes in a single argument, which belongs to the class `HttpContext` in NET Framework Class Library. 
So I guess I need to prepare an object of `HttpContext`.

All that the method needs from the argument, say `context`, are

- `context.Request.QueryString`
- `context.Request.Headers`

Here are my thoughts and questions

1. To learn how to use `HttpContext`, I click going to definition in
   Visual Studio, I found that the class has a constructor

   ```
       public HttpContext(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response);
   ```

   so I need to provide its two arguments, in order to create a object
   of the class.

   To provide the first argument, which is an object of HttpRequest, I found its constructor

   ```
   //
   // Summary:
   //     Initializes an System.Web.HttpRequest object.
   //
   // Parameters:
   //   filename:
   //     The name of the file associated with the request.
   //
   //   url:
   //     The information regarding the URL of the current request.
   //
   //   queryString:
   //     The entire query string sent with the request (everything after the'?').
   public HttpRequest(string filename, string url, string queryString);
   ```

   - What does `filename` mean?
   - Which is `url`, the full url containing the query strings, or just the part before `?`?

   To provide the second argument of class `HttpResponse`, I found its constructor

   ```
   public HttpResponse(TextWriter writer);
   ```

   The method to be tested actually doesn't need `context.Response`. So can I simply create this as the second argument to the constructor of `HttpContext`:

   ```
   writer = new TextWriter ();
   response = new HttpResponse(writer);
   ```

   given that the constructors of `TextWriter` are protected?

   ```
   protected TextWriter();
   protected TextWriter(IFormatProvider formatProvider);
   ```
2. After I can create an object of HttpContext, do I need to call some
   method to parse the url and query strings to obtain

   - `context.Request.QueryString`
   - `context.Request.Headers`

   or the `HttpContext` will implicitly do the work without me
   explicitly calling any method?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably contain useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4379450/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452418/11683

Comment: Some sample code to create a mock HTTPContext here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10126711/4191475