# Why MVC base classes has extremely different implementation than WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

From along time i need to ask a question which shouldn't be but please its things around on humans head.

*Why MVC has different implementation for Server, Respone, etc that WebForms ?*

**In MVC depends on :**

- MVC Session  **HttpSessionStateBase** -> came from System.Web
- MVC Server   **HttpServerUtilityBase**
- MVC Request  **HttpRequestBase**
- MVC Respone  **HttpResponseBase**
- MVC Context  **HttpContextBase**

**But in WebForms :**

- WebForms Session **HttpSessionState**  -> came from System.Web.SessionState
- HttpServerUtility
- HttpRequest
- HttpResponse
- HttpContext

Also in MVC the HttpContext is a property of controller. but in WebForms the HttpContext is just a static class there.

Looks like MVC put Wrappers classes for WebForms one ? or idont know.

```
HttpSessionStateWrapper

HttpContextWrapper
```

I just wondered why all of these things are different ? does the specialists who write libraries make it like these for appears nice not ugly ?

Comment: But. its strange that implementation are strange !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

MVC *does* use `HttpRequest`, `HttpContext`, `HttpResponse`, etc. It just doesn't use them *directly*.

By depending on the "base" classes it allows you to substitute your own implementations which inherit from those abstract classes. That enables us to write unit tests for controllers or other classes that depend on context, request, etc.

At runtime it takes `HttpRequest` and wraps it in a class called [`HttpRequestWrapper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestwrapper) which also inherits from `HttpRequestBase`, since `HttpRequest` does not inherit from `HttpRequestBase`. (And the same pattern for the other classes.)

---

Technically MVC uses the same classes as WebForms at runtime. It just doesn't *directly* depend on them. Instead it depends on the base classes. At runtime it uses wrapper classes like `HttpContextWrapper` which inherit from the base class but actually "wrap" an instance of `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest`, etc.

By depending on abstract classes like `HttpContextBase` instead of concrete classes like `HttpContext`, the MVC framework enables you to "mock" those classes by providing alternate implementations of the abstract classes. [Here's a popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq) on that. It's not extremely simple, but at least it's not impossible.

In contrast, unit testing was much more difficult with WebForms. Most of the testing strategy for WebForms involved keeping as much as possible out of them and putting it in other testable classes. But when it came to anything involving the request, response, context, etc., it was difficult. Apparently it [wasn't impossible](https://www.simplethread.com/using-systemwebabstractions-in-your-webforms-apps/), but you had to do some weird custom stuff in your pages instead of using the `Context` or `Page` properties.

Comment: Why Also in MVC the HttpContext is a property of controller. but in WebForms the HttpContext is just a static class there.