# The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

```
public static string RazorViewRender(object model, string filePath)
{
     var sw = new StringWriter();
     var context = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
     var routeData = new RouteData() ;
     HomeController home= new HomeController();
     var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(context, routeData), home);
     var razor = new RazorView(controllerContext, filePath, null, false, null);
     razor.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, razor, new ViewDataDictionary(model), new TempDataDictionary(), sw), sw);
     return sw.ToString();
}
```

in this code,

> razor.render

line program gives error

> 'The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a
>   non-empty string value.'

i guess it can't find my homecontroller, my project has areas. How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add route data. Exception tell you everything.

```
var routeData = new RouteData() ;
routeData.Values.Add("Controller", "Home");
routeData.Values.Add("Action", "Index");
```

Comment: Hi Onur, can you add more details? What exactly is route data?